# How can i create a custom button, when pressed will create and insert a new Quote?

Tags: apex, button, custom

I need to create a custom button on my Opportunity Page Layout and when it is pressed this button needs to create automatically a Quote. Basically, the point of this is to avoid clicking so much. I wrote some code but I don't know if it's good or bad and I don't know how to continue to this.

```
public class MyController {
public String currentRecordId {get;set;}
public String parameterValue {get;set;}
public Opportunity opp {get;set;}

public MyController(ApexPages.StandardController controller){
    currentRecordId = ApexPages.currentPage().getparameters().get('id');
    opp = [Select id From Opportunity where id =: currentRecordId];
    parameterValue =ApexPages.currentPage().getparameters().get('nameParam');

    Quote qo = new Quote();
    insert qo;
  }
}
```

Comment: Is this requirement specific to lightning or classic as well?

Comment: we work in classic, hence only classic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All you need is:-

Create a Controller with a method createrecord with return type pagerefernce. Here I am creating a quote related to that Opportunity and redirect to newly created quote:-

```
public class quoteController {

    public String currentRecordId {get;set;}
    public Opportunity opp {get;set;}

    public quoteController(ApexPages.StandardController controller){
        currentRecordId = ApexPages.currentPage().getparameters().get('id');
        opp = [Select id, Accountid From Opportunity where id =: currentRecordId];
    }
    public PageReference createquote(){
         Quote qo = new Quote();
        qo.Opportunityid=opp.id;
        qo.Name='Test';
        insert qo;
        PageReference pr = new PageReference('/' +qo.id);
                 pr.setRedirect(true);
        return pr;
    }
}
```

Now, create a visualforce page and call that method in this page as follows:-

```
<apex:page extensions="quoteController" standardController="Opportunity" action="{!createquote}">
</apex:page>
```

> Now, go to setup--> opportunity-->button links and action--> create a
>   new button---> content source-- visualforce page-->fill other
>   details-->save it-->add it to opportunity layout Remember to add your button display behaviour as **Display in existing window without sidebar or header**

Your custom quote button is ready. Hope it helps You.

Comment: humar

I create a new button just how you said it, so I went to etup--> opportunity-->button links and action--> new button or link --> selected Detail Page button --> Display in new window --> URL --> in body i added /apex/quoteVF --> saved it.

I added the button to Opportunity page layout and when i click it it says:

List has no rows for assignment to SObject 
An unexpected error has occurred. Your development organization has been notified.

What I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: Use display behavior Display in existing window without sidebar or header

Comment: damn, i still have the same error with last has no rows.

Comment: @Franken you should not use the content source as url. use Content Source as Visualforce Page.

Comment: yep, it works:D thank you very much! And if i want to redirect to a custom visualforce i can change this: 

partPageReference pr = new PageReference('/' +qo.id);
pr.setRedirect(true);
return pr;

I have a custom VF page that needs to be shown after I click the button with couple of fields.

Comment: @Franken exactly, You just change the address ('/' +qo.id) as ('/apex/yourvfpage'). Mark it as your answer and upvote it.